# how to transfer data from TabBarController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

[image]
how to transfer data from a TabBarController to the controllers that are in it, if there is still a NavigationController between them

```
import UIKit

class MainTabBarViewController: UITabBarController {
    
    var currentUser: MUser = MUser(username: "fdff",
                                   usersurname: "dfdf",
                                   phone: "dffd",
                                   sex: "dfb",
                                   avatarStringURL: "fgf",
                                   id: "gf",
                                   bithDate: "fggf")
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let messageVC = self.navigationController?.viewControllers [3] as! MessageVC
        messageVC.currentUser = currentUser
 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let navigationController = viewControllers?[2] as? UINavigationController,
    let messageVC = navigationController.viewControllers.first as? MessageVC  {
    messageVC.currentUser = currentUser
}
```